# read every 2nd value every 4 rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, row, read-csv

I am trying to read only the values of every 4th row of my excel data sheet (every value corresponding to "media"). I can do this but I want to read every 4th row, starting from row 2. Or technically it would be row 2 and row 6 and row 10 etc. But no matter what I try I can't get what I want. [excel datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yKv8.png)

I tried variations that I found from different questions:

```
cols=[' estacion_id','estacion_nombre','sensor_id','sensor_alias','sensor_nombre','fecha_ observacio n','metrica','valor' ]  
f=pd.read_csv('env_picacho-ma_2013.csv', usecols=['fecha_observacion', 'valor'])

date=pd.read_csv('env_picacho-ma_2013.csv', usecols=['fecha_observacion'],skiprows=lambda x: logic(x)  )
temp=pd.read_csv('env_picacho-ma_2013.csv', usecols=['valor'],skiprows= lambda x:(x % 4))
```

This gives me every 4th row:
valor
0       7.7
1       8.4
2       4.7
3       6.8
4       8.2
...     ...
1820  791.0
1821  771.0
1822  841.0
1823  806.0
1824  795.0

I also tried:

```
def logic(index=0):

if index % 4 == 3:
    return True

return False

temp=pd.read_csv('env_picacho-ma_2013.csv', usecols=['valor'],skiprows= lambda x: logic(x))
```

This skips every 3rd row out of 4. So I thought I could just skip every row1 and row3 and row4 in order to keep only row2. But this doesn't work either:

```
def logic(index=0):

if index % 4 == 3 and index % 4== 2:
    return True

return False
```

gives me all the values again. I can sort of understand why this wold not work because I am contradicting myslef but I don't know how to do it right:

```
        valor
```

0             NaN
1         3.78417
2         0.60000
3         7.70000
4             NaN
...           ...
7295    806.00000
7296  20382.00000
7297          NaN
7298          NaN
7299    795.00000

I then found this which selects every top 2 values every 5 rows but I don't know how to modify this for my case (every 2nd value every 4 rows):

```
df.groupby(df.index//5).head(2)
```

I tried quite a few variations and I guess my other option would either be a loop but I am terrible at coding loops so if anyone can offer any advice it would be much appreciated.
What I want is:
valor
0     3.78417
1     4.48482
2     2.38661
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am trying to read only ... (every value corresponding to "**media**").*

You can use :

```
SR, GAP = 2, 3

df = pd.read_csv("env_picacho-ma_2013.csv", # add more params if needed
                 skiprows=lambda i: (i+SR)%(GAP+1) and i!=0)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

    estacion_id estacion_no  sensor_id  ... fecha_observacion metrica valor
0            90  PICACHO_MA        225  ...        01/01/2013   media  3.78
1            90  PICACHO_MA        225  ...        02/01/2013   media  4.48
2            90   PICACHO_M        225  ...        03/01/2013   media  2.39
3            90  PICACHO_M.        225  ...        04/01/2013   media  3.18
4            90  PICACHO_M.        225  ...        05/01/2013   media  3.86
5            90  PICACHO_MA        225  ...        06/01/2013   media  2.27
6            90  PICACHO_MA        225  ...        07/01/2013   media  2.42
7            90  PICACHO_MA        225  ...        08/01/2013   media  0.89
8            90  PICACHO_M.        225  ...        09/01/2013   media  2.07
9            90  PICACHO_M.        225  ...        10/01/2013   media  2.90
10           90   PICACHO M        225  ...        11/01/2013   media  3.95
```

Intermediates (*callable*) :

```
index  0 # --> False (don't skip)
index  1 # -->  True
index  2 # --> False (don't skip)
index  3 # -->  True
index  4 # -->  True
index  5 # -->  True
index  6 # --> False (don't skip)
index  7 # -->  True
index  8 # -->  True
index  9 # -->  True
index 10 # --> False (don't skip)
index 11 # -->  True
index 12 # -->  True
index 13 # -->  True
index 14 # --> False (don't skip)
index 15 # -->  True
index 16 # -->  True
index 17 # -->  True
index 18 # --> False (don't skip)
...
```

Comment: Both answers work great thanks! I then thought it would be easy to add a condition to skip the 1061 first rows before implementing the condition to skip every 4 rows for rows 1062 to 2921 and then skipping rows 2922 to end (basically using nrows) but again I can't seem to get it right. It keeps starting from row 2 . this is what I changed within this solution: SR1, GAP1 = 1062, 3. I tried adding a condition to the def logic of the other solution but same problem.

Comment: You're welcome but you when you talk about the `1061` (*as an index*), do you mean the physical position or the row position in the csv (line number) or the index in terms of pandas ?  It's ambiguous! Anyways, you can try this : `skiprows=lambda i: i%4 if (i==0 or 1061 < i < 2921) else True)`. You may need to adjust one of the interval's edges (or both of them) with `+-1`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the following formula which skips every row except the first row (the header) and rows that don't conform to the pattern 2,6,10,14...

```
def logic(index=0):
    if index==0: # keep the header row
        return False
    if (index+2) % 4 == 0: # keep every 4th row starting from row 2
        return False
    return True

date = pd.read_csv('env_picacho-ma_2013.csv', usecols=['fecha_observacion'],skiprows=lambda x: logic(x))
```